# Getting a user to input multiple values into a calloc array, C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

trying to get my head around memory allocation and pointers in the C programming language.

If I allocate a space in memory for an array like so:

```
int *array = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

Can I then get the user to input multiple values to go into that array like this?

```
printf("Please enter values:\n");
scanf("%d", &*array);
```

Further more does the first line of code create a space in memory for an array and a pointer to that space. ie can I later point to a number in that array using *array? If this is not the case do I need some code along the lines of:

```
int *ptr;
int array;
ptr = array;
```

Quite new to programming so I apologize if my logic is not clearly shown. Also thanks in advance for any help.

Rus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it without a loop. Here is what you can do:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    printf("Please enter value for element %d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
```

> does the first line of code create a space in memory for an array and a pointer to that space?

Yes, it does. In C you do not need to cast the results of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`, so you can re-write that line like this:

```
int *array = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response! Worked perfectly.